# Function calling: Code that fix csv into a certain format

Tags: python, function, csv, import

I have a piece of code that is working to fix my csv. Now I am trying to make it as a function on its own file, that I can use for any arbitrary csv file with same format.

However, I get following error. IndexError: list index out of range when I put the code inside a function.

I have red more about functions, and I am missing something I just can't see

```
# code that works 
with open('File.csv','r') as csv_read: 
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_read)
csv_data = list(csv_reader)
if csv_data[0][0] == '':
    csv_data[0][0] = 'Time Stamp'
    del csv_data[1]
    del csv_data[1]
    print('CSV has been fixed')
else:
    print('Has already been fixed')
with open('File.csv', 'wb') as writerFile_csv:
writer_csv = csv.writer(writerFile_csv)
writer_csv.writerows(csv_data)
csv_read.close()
writerFile_csv.close()

# code that does not work
def FixCSV(File):
    with open(File, 'r') as csv_read:
         csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_read)
         csv_data = list(csv_reader)
         csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_read)
         csv_data = list(csv_reader)
         if csv_data[0][0] == '':
            csv_data[0][0] = 'Time Stamp'
            del csv_data[1]
            del csv_data[1]
            print(File +' has been fixed')
         else:
            print(File + 'Has already been fixed')
     with open(File, 'wb') as writerFile_csv:
         writer_csv = csv.writer(writerFile_csv)
         writer_csv.writerows(csv_data)
     csv_read.close()
     writerFile_csv.close()
FixCSV('File.csv')
```

Result that code that works:

```
 Time Stamp, /xxxx   /130     /T3      /-P*     /xxxx,
```

from

```
, /xxx  /130     /T3      /-P*     /xxxx, 
Time Stamp, Value,
```

Comment: Strange, both your `code that works` and `code that does not work` sections crash on my machine. The first has an IndentationError, and the second has a NameError. Are you certain the code in this question 100% matches what you're running?

Comment: Tried to fix the indent, my misstake.  Problably when copying from notepad++ to stack. I am not so used to to stack format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are reading from **list(csv_reader)** into **csv_data** which results into an empty list. So when you access  **csv_data[0][0]**, it gives list index out of range error.

Comment: ahhh, I see it.

Comment: kindly accept the answer if it solves your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I have double

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_read)
csv_data = list(csv_reader)
```

Good lesson learned. Make sure to take coffe break. Stupid misstake of mine. Sorry for wasting your time folks.